# How to redirect logged in user to subdomain using Firebase Auth and Hosting?

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

My primary domain is `domain.com` that I plan to use as a landing page. I have a subdomain of `app.domain.com` for the actual webapp site. My desired outcome is as follows:

- **Not Logged In**: `domain.com` -> `domain.com/login` -> `app.domain.com`
- **Logged In**: redirected to `app.domain.com`

Is this possible with Firebase Hosting? I see now Firebase allows different sites in the same project. Would I use this to create two different sites and just redirect on the client side? That's the only way I see can work while keeping the auth state across the app. Is there a better way to do this, as it seems to be pretty a common use case?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a need for authentication on the root domain at all?

If not, you can place the login page on the subdomain and not add the complexity of authentication across two domains.